# Example for a non-trivial PCP verifier for an NP-complete problem

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, np-complete, approximation, randomized-algorithms

During my involvement in a course on dealing with NP-hard problems I have encountered the PCP theorem, stating

$\qquad\displaystyle \mathsf{NP} = \mathsf{PCP}(\log n, 1)$.

I understand the technical definition of a PCP verifier, so I know in principle what kind of algorithm has to exist for every NP problem: a randomised algorithm that checks $O(1)$ bits of the given certificate for the given input using $O(\log n)$ random bits, so that this algorithm is essentially a one-sided error Monte-Carlo verifier.

However, I have trouble imagining how such an algorithm can deal with an NP-complete problem. Short of reading the proof of the PCP theorem, are there concrete examples for such algorithms?

I skimmed the relevant sections of [Computational Complexity: A Modern Approach](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/theory/complexity/) by Arora and Barak (2009) but did not find any.

An example using a $\mathsf{PCP}(\_,\ll n)$ algorithm would be fine.

Comment: Did you see chapter 11 (PCP theorem and hardness of approximation: An introduction) in Arora-Barak? It contains simple PCPs for graph non-isomorphism, permanent and a proof of $\mathsf{NP} \subseteq \mathsf{PCP}(n^3,1)$ (which is _far_ easier than $\mathsf{PCP}(\log n,1)$).

Comment: See [this reading group](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/theory/PCPReadingGroup.html).

Comment: For the permanent, you can check [this writeup](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~yuvalf/permanent.pdf).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following up on a comment by [sdcvvc](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/667/sdcvvc) I checked out example 11.7 in [Computational Complexity: A Modern Approach](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/theory/complexity/) by Arora and Barak ([Draft](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/theory/index.php/Compbook/Draft#pcp) of 2008). There, the authors describe a "PCP algorithm" for the problem *Graph Non-Isomorphism* (GNI):

> **Input:** Two graphs $G_0$ and $G_1$ with $n$ vertices each.
>
> **Output:** Accept if and only if $G_0$ and $G_1$ are not isomorph (write
>   $G_0 \not\equiv G_1$).

We denote the certificate (they call it "proof") by $\pi$ and with $\pi(i)$
the $i$-th bit of $\pi$.

The algorithm $A$ proceeds as follows:

- Choose a bit $b \in \{0,1\}$ uniformly at random.
- Choose a permutation $\sigma \in S_n$ (of the vertices of $G_b$).
- Accept if $\pi(\langle\sigma(G_b)\rangle) = b$, reject otherwise.

Here, $\langle \_ \rangle$ is some computable bijection from $\mathbb{N}^n$
to a suitable range $[0..N] \subseteq \mathbb{N}$. We assume that if the derefenced 
bit in $\pi$ does not exist, i.e. the certificate is too short, we reject.

**Claim:** By above algorithm, GNI is in $\operatorname{PCP}(n \log n, 1)$, i.e.

1. the algorithm uses $O(n \log n)$ random bits and queries $O(1)$ bits of $\pi$,
2. $(G_0, G_1) \in \mathrm{GNI}$ implies that there is some certificate $\pi$
    so that $\Pr[A(G_0, G_1, \pi) \text{ accepts}] = 1$, and
3. $(G_0, G_1) \notin \mathrm{GNI}$ implies that 
    $\Pr[A(G_0, G_1, \pi) \text{ rejects}] \geq \tfrac{1}{2}$ for *all* certificates
    $\pi \in \{0,1\}^*$.

**Ad 1:** Clear from the algorithm by noting that uniform permutation sampling
is possible with $\approx n \log n$ random bits¹.

**Ad 2:** Consider the certificate

$\qquad\displaystyle \pi(\langle H \rangle) = 
  \begin{cases}
0 &, H \equiv G_0, H \not\equiv G_1 \\
1 &, H \equiv G_1, H \not\equiv G_0 \\
\text{arbitrary} &, \text{ otherwise}
  \end{cases}$

where $H$ are all graphs with $n$ nodes. Since $G_0 \not\equiv G_1$ and
$\sigma(G_b) \equiv G_b$, we have $\sigma(G_b) \not\equiv G_{1-b}$ for all $b$ and 
$\sigma$. The query to $\pi$ therefore always yields $b$ and thus always accept.

**Ad 3:** Let $\pi \in \{0,1\}^*$ arbitrary and $H = \sigma(G_b)$ the chosen
query graph. If our query hits a non-existing bit of $\pi$ we reject by assumption, 
which is correct. Otherwise, we calculate

$\qquad\begin{align}
  \Pr[\text{accept}] &= \Pr[b=0] \cdot \frac{\#[\pi(H) = 0 \mid H \equiv G_0]}{\#[H \equiv G_0]}
                  + \Pr[b=1] \cdot \frac{\#[\pi(H) = 1 \mid H \equiv G_1]}{\#[H \equiv G_1]} \\
                 &= \frac{1}{2} \cdot \left( \frac{\#[\pi(H) = 0 \mid H \equiv G_0]}{\#[H \equiv G_0]} +
                                             \frac{\#[\pi(H) = 1 \mid H \equiv G_0]}{\#[H \equiv G_0]}
                                     \right) \\
                 &= \frac{1}{2}                                         
\end{align}$
using that $H \equiv G_1 \iff H \equiv G_0$ in this case.

Thus, the claim is proven.

---

Some observations that helped me grasp these concepts better.

- The certificate $\pi$ can be arbitrarily long and arbitrarily complex. Note that
  "good" certificates for the above algorithm essentially solve the same problem
  as the algorithm (many times).
- But that does not imply that any decision problem can be solved in PCP style
  by "just providing the answer in the certificate". Condition 3 prevents any
  naive attempt of that kind.
- It is in general not possible to derive an efficient (randomised one-sided-error) 
  algorithm that guesses the certificate (as is the case for NP-certificate verifiers).

---

1. Strictly speaking, this assumes that $n!=2^k$ (which of course almost never holds) 
   since we [have infinite worst-case runtime](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/2605) 
   for other $n$. However, Arora/Barak seem to ignore this aspect.

Comment: I'd appreciate a comment about the footnote. Did I miss something, can we gloss over this with good conscience or is it a serious bug ?

Comment: You can use rejection sampling to sample a random permutation with arbitrarily small constant failure probability using $O(n\log n)$ bits; in case of failure, you can choose the identity permutation. This way all three properties are satisfied. (You may have to repeat the test to get a probability of $1/2$ in the final property.)

Answer (score 2):

Two problems that might help develop intuition:

1. Prove that $\mathsf{AM} \subseteq \mathsf{PCP}(\text{poly}(n),1)$. You are allowed to assume $\mathsf{NP} \subseteq \mathsf{PCP}(\text{poly}(n),1)$.
2. Prove that $\mathsf{PSPACE} \subseteq \mathsf{PCP}(\text{poly}(n),\text{poly}(n))$. Hint:

> Use IP = PSPACE

Trivia: The first exercise subsumes the PCP for GNI, while the second subsumes the PCP for permanent. Both results are subsumed by $\mathsf{NEXP} = \mathsf{PCP}(\text{poly}(n),1)$.