# How can you shuffle in $O(n)$ time if you need $\Omega(n \log n)$ random bits?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, randomized-algorithms

A shuffling algorithm is supposed to generate a random permutation of a given finite set. So, for a set of size $n$, a shuffling algorithm should return any of the $n!$ permutations of the set uniformly at random.

Also, conceptually, a randomized algorithm can be viewed as a deterministic algorithm of the input and some random seed. Let $S$ be any shuffling algorithm. On input $X$ of size $n$, its output is a function of the randomness it has read. To produce $n!$ different outputs, $S$ must have read at least $\log(n!) = \Omega(n \log n)$ bits of randomness. Hence, any shuffling algorithm must take $\Omega(n \log n)$ time.

On the other hand, the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) is [widely](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/the-danger-of-naivete.html) [believed](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?LinearShuffle) to run in $O(n)$ time. Is there something wrong with my argument? If not, why is this belief so widespread?

Comment: Precisely what is your model of computation? For example, if you use the word-RAM model with $\Theta(\log n)$-bit words, then in $\Theta(n)$ time you can read $\Theta(n \log n)$ bits of data.

Comment: [Related question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1643/how-can-we-assume-comparison-addition-between-numbers-is-o1)

Comment: @JukkaSuomela I would look at any model of computation that can read an unbounded amount of data in constant time a bit suspiciously.

Answer (score 12):

Your argument appears to be perfectly valid (Fisher-Yates does indeed require $\log (n!)$ bits of randomness), the discrepancy comes in by making different assumptions about the complexity of the random number generation.

You're assuming generating a random number between $0$ and $n$ takes $O(\log n)$.

But, when saying that the Fisher-Yates shuffle is $O(n)$, one assumes generating a random number takes $O(1)$.

An integer index (which is used in the Fisher-Yates shuffle) is generally considered $O(1)$ space (even though it's technically $O(\log n)$) because you can index way more data with a simple 64-bit integer than can currently reasonably fit into the memory of any computer most of us have access to $^{1}$. And the space complexity per number is same as the complexity for the number of random bits that must be generated for that number.

1: To go beyond the number of elements a 64-bit integer can index, we would require $2^{64}$ = $18446744073709551616$ elements, and, assuming 1 bit (which is obviously very small) per element, this requires 2 [exabytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exabyte).

Comment: I am not making any assumptions about the complexity of random number generation. Just to read $\Omega(n \log n)$ random bits would still require $\Omega(n \log n)$ time.

Comment: The same applies whether we're talking about generating them or reading them.

Comment: @AlexSmart To be more specific: the number of random bits is certainly a lower bound on the (total) time a random bit generator takes to generate them. Of course, reading them yields a lower bound on the whole algorithm -- depending on your cost model.

Comment: @AlexSmart: I can read $\Omega(n \log n)$ random bits in $\Omega(n)$ time if I have $\Omega(\log n)$ processors working in parallel. If you're going to count each individual operation on a $\Theta(b)$-bit register as $\Theta(b)$ operations, then you also have to acknowledge that your processor is built out of circuits that do $\Theta(b)$ operations in parallel.

Answer (score 6):

In the analysis of Fisher-Yates shuffle and similar algorithms we typically assume that we can draw a number from $[1..n]$ uniformly at random in time $O(1)$. Also, we usually assume a RAM model with uniform cost, that is we can read such numbers in time $O(1)$, too.

If you include random number generation into your runtime analysis (which you probably *should* do), make sure to be clear about whether you are talking about worst-case or expected time.

Depending on what kind of random source you have at hand, assuming constant-time random number generation may or may not be warrented. For instance, a (black-box, constant-time) source of $\mathcal{U}(0,1)$  (uniform) real numbers can be used thus, but a $\mathcal{B}(0.5)$ (Bernoulli) bit source can not. See [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2605/is-rejection-sampling-the-only-way-to-get-a-truly-uniform-distribution-of-random) for details.